# Magento process credit card with PayPal without redirect to PayPal

Tags: magento, payment-gateway, paypal, payment

i'd like to know if is it possible to process credit card information using PayPal Pro as a gateway without redirection to PayPal page. What we want is to show the form inside our store, make an API call and print the response to the user without make him leaving to paypal.

We are are using Magento 1.4.2, is there any existing solution ? otherwise we have to develop one by ourself

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is called Reference Transactions.  This will allow you to do one-click payments or store and bill a user's PayPal account like a credit card, without redirecting to PayPal; however, you *will* have to initially redirect the customer to PayPal the first time in order to get the customer's consent for this.

You also need approval from PayPal to use Reference Transactions, so not all merchants will be able to utilize this feature.

I'm not familiar with Magento so I can't comment on how you would implement this specifically on that platform, but using Reference Transactions are how you'd do it.

https://www.x.com/devzone/articles/recurring-payments-reference-transactions-and-preapproved-payments

https://www.x.com/developers/community/blogs/ppintegrationsnate/express-checkout-reference-transactions

Answer (score 1):

You can make paypal show up in a frame and use their API with its secure keys, etc. I do believe Josh's answer is technically not correct, but PP is a big enough pain to code for, we settled on doing anything we could get to work, which is redirect to their site.

Don't worry, paypal users are accustomed to this and don't mind.

Answer (score 0):

That's a negative. PayPal is very strict in how they take payment information. Even if you found a way to get around the redirection that is required, you would probably be shut down within a few seconds of someone at PayPal noticing what you are doing.

Not to mention the fact that doing this would probably set off a red flag in the minds of anyone that is checking out at your store since you are doing something so different than anyone else. The more hardcore PayPal users will just assume that you are phishing (and then you could possibly see your ISP shut your site down if they get a complaint).

I guess, what I am trying to say is, this is a really really bad idea.